# how to do parsing by quotes and commas subject to quotation marks at the beginning or end?

Tags: c#, .net

My program takes a string from the file and divides it into quotes and then into commas, all commas in quotes are part of the text.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] source = File.ReadAllLines("file.csv", Encoding.Default);

        string src = source[0];

        //text preparation for spliting
        string modifiedSrc = src.Replace("\",", "\"").Replace(", \"", "\"");

        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        string [] parts = modifiedSrc.Split('\"');

        //odd elements separated by quotes, even by commas
        data.AddRange(parts.Where((x, index) => index % 2 != 0));
        data.AddRange(parts.Where((x, index) => index % 2 == 0).SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')));
        string result = string.Join(" | ", data.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

text: cat, dog, "big, snake", wolf
will show: cat | dog | big, snake | wolf

text: cat, dog, "big, snake", human, "wild, wolf"
will show: cat | dog | big, snake | human | wild, wolf

**BUT** if there is only one text in quotes and it is not correct at the end or at the beginning:
text: "big, cat", dog,  human 
will show: big, cat | dog, human

**dog, human** not shared on: dog | human

How to fix such a special case? I was forbidden to use the library side.

CSV-file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DtjK6LcI0KLY7B59wD_KkFP3KxZadm5-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I ran your code and it runs as expected can you pleas post your csv file. I really feel the error is in the csv file.

Comment: [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: What happens if there is a space between the comma and the double quote?  What happens if there is no space or two spaces?